# How to invoke recoding sound/voice functionality in android

Tags: android

Can you please tell me where I can find example in how to invoke andord recoding sound/voice functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/

And...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Easy  =)